# echo two fields data subtracted from each other in php

Tags: php

```
echo "<<td>td>".$rec["year1"] * $rec["year2"]."<</td>/td>";
```

Now this works. But when I replace '*' with a '-' (minus) it doesn't work and gives the list of 4rec["id"] values with minus symbol infront. (ie. -10-12-14 etc;)

Please help. Thanks

Comment: try `echo "<<td>td>".($rec["year1"] - $rec["year2"])."<</td>/td>";`

Comment: Have you tried including parentheses? `. ($rec['year1'] - $rec['year2']) . `

Comment: I would use INT to convert them to integers -- ((int)$rec["year1"] - (int)$rec["year2"])

Comment: The concatenation operator has (*sigh*) higher precedence than the subtraction operator. It took me a couple of hours to track that one down when I came across it a few weeks back.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td><td>".( (int)$rec["year1"] - (int)$rec["year2"])."</td>/td>";
```

Comment: He's asking a question about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use comma and brackets:

```
echo "<td>", ( (int)$rec["year1"] - (int)$rec["year2"]), "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert them:

```
echo "<td>" . (intval($rec["year1"]) - intval($rec["year2"])) . "</td>";
```

Also modified HTML because was wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

Just put parentheses around the equation, like:

```
echo "<td>" . ($rec["year1"] - $rec["year2"]) . "</td>";
```